# where are deleted files kept?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Ubuntu 9.10

I recently deleted some files. I would like to know are the files kept in a directory? Like in windows recycle bin. I would like to know where these files are?

Comment: Did you delete them in Nautilus or using `rm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubuntu 9.10 they go to *$HOME/.local/share/Trash* as specified by the [Desktop Trash Can Specification](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/trash-spec)

Answer (score -1):

Deleted files are found in $HOME/.Trash